# Execute two JS functions in one event independently

Tags: javascript, function

I need to print a result from execution of first function to innerHTML, without waiting execution of second function. Both functions should be called by clicking a button.

How it should be:

```
<p id="t1">Log</p>
<script>
document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML = '1';  

setTimeout(function afterTwoSeconds() {
  document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML = '2';
}, 2000);
</script>
```

Firstly appears "1", then after two seconds "2".

If I put in button event two functions consequently, result from "One" waiting until "Two" completes, and "1" is not appear:

```
<p id="t1">Log</p>
<input type=button value="two functions" onclick="one(); two();">

<script>
function one() {
  document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML = '1'; 
}

function two() {
  var date = new Date();
  var curDate = null;
  do { curDate = new Date(); }
  while(curDate-date < 2000);
  document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML  = '2';
}
</script>
```

If I call "Two" as a callback from "One", result is the same, "1" is also not appear:

```
<p id="t1">Log</p>
<input type=button value="callback" onclick="one_callback(two);">

<script>
function one_callback(callback) {
  document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML = '1'; 
  callback();
}

function two() {
  var date = new Date();
  var curDate = null;
  do { curDate = new Date(); }
  while(curDate-date < 2000);
  document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML  = '2';
}
</script>
```

How can I get a result from function "One" without waiting execution of "Two"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should use setTimeout or setInterval function.

```
function one_callback(callback) {
  document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML = '1'; 

  setTimeout(function() {callback(); }, 2000);
}

function two() {  
  document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML  = '2';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, He Zhi Yong. But I don't understand yet.
This works as it schould:

```
<script>
function one_callback(callback) {
  document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML = '1'; 
  callback();
}

function two() {
  setTimeout(function() { 
    var date = new Date();
    var curDate = null;
    do { curDate = new Date(); }
    while(curDate-date < 2000);
    document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML  = '2';
   }, 0);
}
</script>
```

but when I put away setTimeout, "1" does not appears, and result appears only when "two" is completely executed, i.e. "2" only after 2 secons:

```
<script>
function one_callback(callback) {
  document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML = '1'; 
  callback();
}

function two() {
//  setTimeout(function() { 
    var date = new Date();
    var curDate = null;
    do { curDate = new Date(); }
    while(curDate-date < 2000);
    document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML  = '2';
//   }, 0);
}
</script>
```